# How to show largest digit from a number - javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this function that calculates the largest digit from a number:

```
function maxDigit(n){
  if(n == 0){ 
       return 0;
      }
  else{
    return Math.max(n%10, maxDigit(n/10));
  }
}
console.log(maxDigit(16984));
```

and the returned value is 9.840000000000003

How can I modifiy this code in order to return just the value 9 ?

Comment: `Math.max.apply(null, String(n).split(""))` ;)

Comment: @thg435: `Math.max.apply(null, String(n).replace(/\D/g,'').split('')` or `… String(n).match(/\d/g)`, otherwise you'll get `NaN` from the decimal dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no integer div in Javascript, and this is what you must mean when using '/'.
So either use Math.floor, or substract the remainder :

```
function maxDigit(n){
  if(n == 0){ return 0;}
  else{
    var remainder = n % 10
    return Math.max(remainder, maxDigit((n-remainder)*1e-1));
  }
}
console.log(maxDigit(16984));

// output is 9
```

(the iterative version is quite easy to deduce :

```
function maxDigit(n){
  n= 0 | n ;
  var max=-1, remainder=-1;
  do {
    remainder = n % 10;
    max = (max > remainder ) ? max : remainder ;
    n=(n-remainder)*1e-1;
  } while (n!=0);
  return max;
}

console.log(maxDigit(16984));
// output is 9

console.log(maxDigit(00574865433));
// output is 8
```

)

Answer (score 1):

```
function maxDigit(n){
  if(n == 0){ return 0;}
  else{
    return Math.max(n%10, maxDigit(Math.floor(n/10)));
  }
}
console.log(maxDigit(16984));
```

Unlike Python and other languages, Javascript converts integers to floats if you divide them by a number which isn't their factor.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
function maxDigit(n) {

    var a = n.toString();
    var b = a.split('');

    return Math.max.apply(null, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Math.floor(maxDigit(16984));
```

Math.floor returns the largest integer less than or equal to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below:

```
Math.floor( maxDigit(16984) );
Math.ceil( maxDigit(16984) ); 
Math.round( maxDigit(16984));
```

Comment: Why would you `ceil` or `round` it? `10` is not a digit…

Answer (score 0):

```
const value = 52;
const maxValue = Math.max(...value.toString())
console.log(maxValue);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.